# Get input from HTML via post-function to php

Tags: php, html

I am a complete beginner. I use this function to start my php script which sends userdata to a mysql table:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHODE"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $fullname = trim($_POST['name']);
```

When I trigger this button:

```
<div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <button methode="post" name="submit" value="submit" class="login100-form-btn">
                            Register
                        </button>
                    </div>
```

The page refreshes and everything i filled out is empty. There is no new entry in the mysql-database

Comment: `REQUEST_METHODE` does not exist: [`REQUEST_METHOD`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) does

Comment: No need to check for request method. When you check for `$_POST[]` and fields are set, the post method was used.

Comment: _Side note:_ It's also good practice to check if each and every value is set before trying to use them.

Comment: the <form> tag is missing. You cannot replace it by attaching method="post" to a button

Answer (score 0):

1. Your html form is invalid, there is no 'methode' in a button, but there is 'method' in : `<form method="post"></form>`

also button should be wrapped by `<form>`

2. like @Markus said, request is not needed, but you should use functions `empty` and `isset` to be sure, that something was send. And don't check for being empty or if is set submit button or input, they will always have a value.
3. so:

```
<!-- html -->
<div class="container-login100-form-btn">
    <form action="path_to_file.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="my_input_name" value="" /><br>
        <button type="submit" value="Register" class="login100-form-btn">
            Register
        </button>
    </form>
</div>

//php
if (isset($_POST['my_input_name']) && !empty(trim($_POST['my_input_name']))) {
    $fullname = $_POST['my_input_name'];
}
```

Comment: _Side note:_ You can set the method on the button as well, using the attribute: `formmethod=''POST`. That would override the `method` on the form.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You are right, and probably i'm old-fashioned ;) . I always use 'method' and don't remember about formmethod ;)

Comment: There's no need to use both `isset()` and `!empty()` together like that. Stick to one or the other, depending on what you're checking for. `isset()` = is defined and not null, `empty()` = is not defined or null or the value  is considered empty (like 0, 0.0, empty string etc)